# Cmdline to get latest file on recursive dir command

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

On my hard disk, I have hundreds subfolders created daily that may contain a specific text file (Tracker.txt).

I would like to create a cmdline or BAT file to get only one result, the latest tracker.txt file, with its full path !

I tried `dir /s tracker.txt /OD` but the result is not filtered by date.

Thank you!

Comment: You've specified DOS, do you mean that? The easiest approach by far would be to use PowerShell but that needs Windows (or now Mac or Linux).

Comment: Izarra6492 - I see that you're new to SU so when you get a moment,
 please look over [Accepting an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to ensure you understand how that works for answers that you find helpful in resolving the task you inquire about.

Comment: Will you ever be back?

Comment: To recursively sort by date in batch, you need a properly sortable date-format (like `YYYY-MM-DD`). [It can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621769/2152082) with a little registry-magic.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the `DIR /B /S /OD "tracker.txt"` command results to a temp log file but have it use the `FOR` loop substitutions to put the date time stamp of each file that matches the name followed by a comma and then the full explicit path and file name (i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm [AM/PM]`).

You then use the `SORT` command against that file to sort all the lines in that file to a new sorted file but with the newest time stamp file at the bottom of the list.

Lastly, you'd run a final `FOR` loop through the final file list using the comma as the delimiter and then only setting the iterator variable in that loop to each full explicit path and when it get to the bottom of that list, this is the newest file that is `SET` last and then you can do something with that last set variable which is the newest file date stamp wise from within all the directories you specify recursively.

---

### Batch Script Example

*Be sure to set the value of the `SET StartDir=` variable to be the root folder where the DIR command starts for finding the files recursively.*

```
@ECHO ON

SET StartDir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test

IF EXIST "%temp%\~dir1temp.dat" DEL /Q /F "%temp%\~dir1temp.dat"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S /OD "%StartDir%\tracker.txt"') DO ECHO %%~TA, %%~FPNXA>>"%temp%\~dir1temp.dat"

IF EXIST "%temp%\~dirsorttemp.dat" DEL /Q /F "%temp%\~dirsorttemp.dat"
SORT "%temp%\~dir1temp.dat">>"%temp%\~dirsorttemp.dat"

FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=," %%A IN (%temp%\~dirsorttemp.dat) DO (SET File=%%~A)

ECHO %File%
:::<command to do something with %file%>
PAUSE
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Sort](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html)
- [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- **`FOR /?` (batch substitutions)**

  ```
  In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
  You can now use the following optional syntax:

  %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
  ```
- [Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)